# How can i use url data from link using PHP

Tags: php, url, math, download, mean

I'm beginner in PHP. I have some URL data like this https://ibb.co/7kQNTmq

I'd like to work with it. You can see there is a date (DD.MM.YY) and a number. Id like to create to some mathematical operation like arithmetic mean per month, etc.I know as the first step I need to get from that URL. How is that possible please? I learn PHP over a month so be easy please :) Also I'm trying work with Presenters (Nette)

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` method to get website/file content.
Some documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

However, it's only work on GET requests. You need to use cURL if you want to send POST or etc.